# How to get an array size at compile time?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

When defining either a C-style array or a C++11 array, one often need to get a compile-time constant to express the size of such array. In C, a macro is used to do such a thing without relying on variable-length array (as it wasn't standard in C99):

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 1024
int some_array[ARRAY_SIZE];
```

or

```
#define countof(ARRAY) (sizeof(ARRAY)/sizeof(ARRAY[0]))
```

In C++, is it possible to define something more idiomatic?

Comment: Why not just use `std::array<int, ARRAY_SIZE>`? [`std::array::size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/size) is already `constexpr`

Comment: @CoryKramer it doesn't work with C-style arrays, that is all. See below how to define a `constexpr countof` which takes C-style arrays, C++11 arrays and tuples.

Comment: You could migrate to `std::vector`:  `std::vector<int> some_array(ARRAY_SIZE);`.  Then use `some_array.size()`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews a `std::vector` is a `std::vector`, an `std::array` and a C-style array are something else.

Comment: One advantage to `std::vector` is that you don't need to pass the capacity to functions.  With an array, you'll pass the address of the start of the array and the capacity.  And yes, I know the differences.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews And how do you get a compile-time constant size of an `std::vector` dear?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your standard-library is C++17-compatible, just use [`std::size(xyz)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size).

If your standard-library doesn't already provide that, it's easy to implement yourself, [the `constexpr`-specifier is C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr).

Comment: Quite interesting that `std::size` is `constexpr` now. How does that affect the usage of the classical `sizeof` operator in modern C++? When to choose one over the other?

Comment: @303 keep in mind that `sizeof` returns the size of an object in bytes, while `std::size` returns the size of an array in elements. Quite different.
The classical C expression for finding the size of an array in elements is `sizeof(myarray)/sizeof(myarray[0])` which is quite subpar but quite similar to the constexpr constrained variant.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out, not sure what I was on when asking that question ;d. Hopefully, your clarification can be useful to other people reading this post.

Answer (score 13):

With C++'s `constexpr`, one could find the compile-time constant size of an array with:

```
template<std::size_t N, class T>
constexpr std::size_t countof(T(&)[N]) { return N; }
```

And use it as follows:

```
int some_array[1024];
static_assert(countof(some_array) == 1024, "wrong size");

struct {} another_array[1];
static_assert(countof(another_array) == 1, "wrong size");
```

See the [full program demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e163fc3a2936e07).

If one likes to work with `std::array` and C-style arrays interchangeably, it is possible, with SFINAE, to add a definition of `countof` taking `std::array`s and `std::tuple`s:

```
template<class Array, std::size_t N = std::tuple_size<Array>::value>
constexpr std::size_t countof(Array&) { return N; }
```

See the [enriched program demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cdd6a10fef861138).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to introduce your own function and do it with STL only then size can be retreived with `std::distance`:

```
#include <utility>
auto size = std::distance(std::begin(some_array), std::end(some_array));
```

It is `constexpr` since C++17

Comment: Beginner here, it seems you don't need c++17 and can simply do `constexpr size_t size = std::end(some_array) - std::begin(some_array);`

Comment: Hello @MarkusvonBroady, your workaround for C++14 is great. If you have C++17, using `std::distance` over operator `-` is better though, as it will work for a greater set of containers (e.g. `std::list`). As an even more generalized solution, I'd suggest `using std::begin, std::end` and callcing `begin(some_array)` and `end(some_array)`. This will allow someone to use it with user-defined containers.